# Is there a component in Python like JPanel?

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I've tried Java gui, but it's my first time doing Python gui.
When switching screens, I need elements like Java's JPanel.
Is there a component in Python that plays the same role as JPanel of Java?